# I want an Object lerping in the y-axis to move along the Z-Axis?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, velocity, rigid-bodies, lerp

I'm currently making a runner type game that **is not randomly generated** in Unity. The player, camera and background stay in the same place (the player movement is clamped) and the hazards come towards the player along the negative Z-Axis with this simple lines of code:

```
public float speed;

private Rigidbody rb;

void Start () {
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
    rb.velocity = transform.forward * -speed;
}
```

And it works fine. Now I want to add asteroids that not only come towards the player, but they move up and down (and repeat) and I tried doing this with Lerp(). I'm not a pro about Lerp so I used a code that I found online that works:

```
public Transform startPos, endPos;
public bool repeatable = true;
public float speed = 1.0f;
public float duration = 3.0f;

float startTime, totalDistance;

IEnumerator Start () {
    startTime = Time.time;

    while(repeatable) {
        yield return RepeatLerp(startPos.position, endPos.position, duration);
        yield return RepeatLerp(endPos.position, startPos.position, duration);
    }
}

void Update () {
    totalDistance = Vector3.Distance(startPos.position, endPos.position);
    if(!repeatable) {
        float currentDuration = (Time.time - startTime) * speed;
        float journeyFraction = currentDuration / totalDistance;
        this.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPos.position, endPos.position, journeyFraction);
    }
}

public IEnumerator RepeatLerp(Vector3 a, Vector3 b, float time) {
    float i = 0.0f;
    float rate = (1.0f / time) * speed;
    while (i < 1.0f) {
        i += Time.deltaTime * rate;
        this.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(a, b, i);
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

What I did is create 2 Empty Objects for the start and end positions and then I put the hazard and two lerping points under another Empty Object, let's call it Parent (So Parent > -Hazard -Start - End). Then I added the moving script along the Z-Axis to the parent empty and it kinda works but is like jumping. So the lerping works but it does not move along the Z-Axis until the lerping function is done, the the object jumps to the new Position in the Z-Axis. So it looks very jumpy and glitchy.

How can I do this so is a smooth movement along the Z-Axis and the lerp still works along the Y?

Thanks!!

PS: I know I could just move the character and camera etc, but for now I would like to keep it this way.

Comment: Questions are marked as having been answered satisfactorily by your *accepting* an answer (as you have done already here). Not be editing something into the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The coroutine `RepeatLerp` acts across several frames, but receives input of type `Vector3`. The actual position of a reference point will change over time, but the argument values `a` and `b` do not change until the coroutine terminates.

So the **immediate** solution is simple: instead of passing `Vector3`, pass reference to `Transform`, and grab its new position each frame. Change your function to this:

```
public IEnumerator RepeatLerp(Transform a, Transform b, float time)
{
    float i = 0.0f;
    float rate = (1.0f / time) * speed;
    while (i < 1.0f)
    {
        i += Time.deltaTime * rate;
        this.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(a.position, b.position, i);
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

And in `Start` funtion the invocation will now be:

```
yield return RepeatLerp(startPos, endPos, duration);
yield return RepeatLerp(endPos, startPos, duration);
```

This will solve your problem, however, having said that, **I strongly suggest you reconsider the way you move your object**. You have a mix of `Rigidbody` semantics with moving objects using `transform`, which is a really bad practice. The engine is not designed to do that and it may cause great performance issues in the future.

In general, if you have colliders on your objects (and it looks like you have) you should move your objects around using only `Rigidbody` and applying velocity / forces to it. Maybe have a look at [Rigidbody.MovePosition](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html) if you want to use `Lerp`, but even better use `Rigidbody.velocity`, like for example (the code below is just schematic):

```
if (transform.position.x > highLimit) rigidbody.velocity -= 2*pulsingSpeed;
if (transform.position.x < lowLimit) rigidbody.velocity += 2*pulsingSpeed;
```

Comment: thank you so much! it did work. But i'm gonna follow your advice and move my objects with Rigidbody